# input forms doesn't save in phpmyadmin

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am new to PHP. My input forms doesn't save any of it in my MySQL database but everytime I press my submit button it shows *"register=success"*,
even though its not inserted in my database and its not showing any errors in any line.

index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>Document</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <form id="BG" class="col-lg-8" action="includes/register.php" method="POST">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="formGroupExampleInput">Firstname</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control col-lg-6" id="formGroupExampleInput" placeholder="Firstname" name="fName">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="formGroupExampleInput2">Lastname</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control col-lg-6" id="formGroupExampleInput2" placeholder="Lastname" name="lName">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="formGroupExampleInput">Plate #</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control col-lg-6" id="formGroupExampleInput" placeholder="Plate #" name="plateNo">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="formGroupExampleInput2">Vehicle brand</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control col-lg-6" id="formGroupExampleInput2" placeholder="Vehicle brand" name="vBrand">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="formGroupExampleInput">color</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control col-lg-6" id="formGroupExampleInput" placeholder="color" name="color">
                </div>
                <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Register</button>

            </form>

        </div>
    </body>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.slim.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</html>
```

conn.php

```
<?php
    $dbSname='localhost';
    $dbUname ='root';
    $pwd='';
    $dbName = 'capstone';

    $conn = mysqli_connect($dbSname,$dbUname,$pwd,$dbName);
```

register.php

```
<?php
    include_once 'includes/conn.php';
    $fname=$_POST['fName'];
    $lName=$_POST['lName'];
    $plateNo=$_POST['plateNo'];
    $vBrand=$_POST['vBrand'];
    $color=$_POST['color'];

    $sql = "INSERT INTO register(name,lastname,Plateno,vehiclebrand,color)
            VALUES($fname,$lName,$plateNo,$vBrand,$color);";

    mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

    header("Location: ../index.php?register=success");

?>
```

I was expecting my input to save data to my MySQL database.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to know if an error is happening when you run your query. So, my recomendation is to change your *.php* script to handle exceptions, like this:

```
<?php
    mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);

    try {
        //start of your code
        $host = "localhost";
        $user = "root";
        $pass = "";
        $db = "capstone";        
        $conn = new mysqli($host,$user,$pass,$db);        
        $sql = "INSERT INTO register(name,lastname,Plateno,vehiclebrand,color)
                            VALUES($fname,$lName,$plateNo,$vBrand,$color);";

        $conn->query($sql);
        //end of your code
    }
    catch(mysqli_sql_exception | Exception $e){ 
        $error="Error #".$e->getCode()." ".$e->getMessage().PHP_EOL;

        if(isset($conn) && get_class($e) == "mysqli_sql_exception")
            $error.="SQLSTATE #".$conn->sqlstate." SQL: $sql".PHP_EOL;

        $error.=$e->getTraceAsString();
        echo(nl2br($error));    
    }
    finally {
        if(isset($result) && $result instanceof mysql_result)
            $result->free();

        if(isset($conn) && is_resource($conn) && get_resource_type($conn) === 'mysql link')
            $conn->close();
   }
?>
```

Once you have an error, you can edit your question and share it.

After you can solve your problem, I would recommend to take a look to this question: [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php), because is important to learn early how to avoid SQL injection, a concerning security problem.

Comment: i found out that include_once was my problem since its in the same folder "includes/" was not necessary

Comment: Good you solve it! Feel free to use the code I shared to handle _mysqli_ errors in your scripts, and take a look to the SQL injection issue if you want to go online.

Comment: thnks again mate!!

Answer (score 0):

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

```
$fname=$_POST['fName'];
$lName=$_POST['lName'];
$plateNo=$_POST['plateNo'];
$vBrand=$_POST['vBrand'];
$color=$_POST['color'];
```

}

I think you should have a if checking if the button isset. If this does not answer your question, pls send the database info So I can check it.

Comment: my problem was on includes_once"includes/conn.ph" . i shouldnt put "includes/" since its in the same folder as "conn.ph" 


BUT BIG THANK YOU FOR YOUR SUGGESTION ANYWAYS

Comment: Sry I could not help :/